# What are the poles of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis

This past exam question has me a little lost. I know I should pick a value for $z$ for which the denominator is zero, but cannot think of more than one pole (there should be more I think because of the later parts of the question).

$$f(z) = \frac{1} { (z^2 + 32)} $$

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: If $\alpha^2=-32$, then $(-\alpha)^2=-32$ too.

Comment: The poles are the roots of -32. There are two of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
z^2+32=0\implies z=\pm\sqrt{32}\,i.
$$